# PHP API маршрутизация запросов

Tags: php, api, маршрутизация

Хочу написать простой web api только на php. Как определять тип запроса и параметры запроса я знаю. На сейте есть папка api в которой хранится index.php которые обрабатывает запросы. Не могу понять как сделать маршрутизацию в запросах, т.е запрос webapi/api/product/1 уйдет никуда.Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно прописать в файле `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f  

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?route=$1
```

Все после www.site.com/ попадает в $_GET['route']

Если вам нужно немного другое правило, то советую в поисковике поискать `htaccess редирект на index.php`